# new case! Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsopported type

Tags: python, sqlite

my code in python:-

```
name1 = 'Ahmad'
name2 = 'Abu'
name3 = 'Ali'

DB.execute("INSERT INTO tablename (A,B,C) values (?,?,?)", (name1,name2,name2))

Database.commit()
Database.close()
```

so, the results that i get is as stated in the title:-

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I have tried many solutions including DB.executemany() but nothings came up..

Please do help me!

Comment: What is the schema for `tablename`?

Comment: what do u mean by schema? i dont get it.. huhu..

Comment: You need to provide the data types of the different columns of table `tablename`. It will be best if you provide the sql statement you've used to create the table.

Comment: owh.. the table is already created by using the phpliteadmin.. the data types are the same for all of the columns.. they are using 'REAL' datatype.. any info i missed?